# How to perform a debian package upgrade

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, deb

I have created a Debian package say a-1.0 which copies some files to a location. now that if the files copied have changed, should i create a new package with new files? or is there any way we can do a upgrade to the package as a-1.1 which replaces the old files with new one?

Is there any perfect tutorial which can say about Debian packaging which also include how we can perform a major and minor upgrade to created .deb package.